# Caching in a Web Farm using windows server 2008 r2 DFS. any example?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-distributed-file-system

Any example, which elaborate managing asp.net mvc 3 cache in web farm (application hosted on multiple servers) using windows server 2008 r2 DFS?

I will appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

For caching in web farm, you can use [Windows Server AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817046%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

The topic is significantly huge. If you have specific problem, we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You mean this stuff? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

It shouldn't be any different then if you're using a non server farm or regular file system.

Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: Hi Andrew, let me reiterate the problem. i am using the asp.net cache however, the application is deployed on two or more servers. let say client send request One and it hit the getOrder on Server A and get cached. however when same client/user request the getOrder, it hits the Server B in this case. this is the problem to sync the cache on both node. I hope that i explained it.

Comment: Ahh I see. Generally I use the cache for throw-away-able data maybe something pulled from an expensive database query or webservice call.

For information like you have, I would usually store the data in the database the sites user. 

Although, it's usually also possible to set the load balance or switch to retain affinity so that during a user's session they always are directed to the same server.